# How to update Delphi Datasnap server?

Tags: delphi, iis, server, windows-services, datasnap

I have build a few apps that receive and send data over a Datasnap server.
I have multiple Datasnap servers running on my customers servers.
The Datasnap server runs as a Windows Service on their machines.

How can I remotely update those servers or what is the best way to do this?

Is it maybe better to make the Datasnap Server run on IIS instead of as a Windows Service?

Can I let the server update itself? Maybe if I make a function that sends the new version of it that it can replace itself?

Comment: This is too broad/opinion based/how-to-do-this

Comment: The "easy" manual way is to connect with VNC to the server, upload the new exe stop the service, replace the exe and restart the service.  What issues do you face that make that troublesome?

Comment: @MichaelVincent And we do this at many many servers(machines)? If we do not have access via VNC?

Comment: @Remi: As Agustin said, the question is very broad.  It also has nothing to do with Delphi.  A DataSnap service running on Windows is either an EXE or a DLL, and it can be replaced/updated the same way any other EXE or DLL may be, with the same restrictions.

Comment: I know it's pretty broad, but the problem is that I don't have a clue on how to do this at all. The best way would be an update function inside the server that let's it update itself, but I don't know if this is possible? BTW the service is an EXE.

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944648/how-can-i-update-a-datasnap-server-while-clients-are-still-connected/968446#968446 makes any sense

Comment: I once wrote an ISAPI extension (a re-write of httpsrvr.dll) which could be used to update (old-style) DataSnap appserver DLLs on the fly, without even interrupting clients' connections (it would put incoming requests on hold, wait to finish any currently running requests, unload the appserver DLL, replace it, reload it and continue serving).

Answer (score 0):

I can see no way of updating the exes on your customers' machines without a) getting them to do it; b) logging in remotely using something like VNC (though I'd be happy to know of a better way).

This is an approach I would consider:

I would look to have a separate application which is called by the service on a regular basis (daily/weekly) that looks for a new versions of software on your server (or somewhere), downloads it stops the service, replaces the service's exe and restarts the service.

In the new service exe I would have something that calls this application periodically, so you only have to do this once.

This assumes the machines that run your software have internet access.

Don't forget to include a mechanism to update the updater application.

Comment: Thanks this seems logical. Only how do you update the updater? Can't go on and on with an application to check for updates for another application.